# i am facing ,data manipulation error, it must be atomic number in r?

Tags: r

When I run the code

```
cols_name <- c(10:15)

for(i in 1:ncol(df_churn[,cols_name]))
{
    df_churn[,cols_name][,i] <- as.factor(mapvalues + (df_churn[,cols_name][,i], from =c("No internet service"),to=c("No")))
}
```

I get the error

```
Error in mapvalues(df_churn[, cols_name][, i], from = c("No internet service"),  : 
  `x` must be an atomic vector.
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you are attempting to replace all "No internet service" responses in columns 10:15 of your dataset with "No"?

Without adjusting your syntax too much try this:

```
cols_index <- 10:15

for(i in cols_index){
    df_churn[,i] <- as.factor(mapvalues(df_churn[,i], from ="No internet service",to="No"))
}
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: cols_index <- 10:15
for(i in cols_index){
+   churn[,i] <- as.factor(mapvalues(churn[,i], from ="No internet service",to="No"))
+ }
Error in mapvalues(churn[, i], from = "No internet service", to = "No") : 
  `x` must be an atomic vector.

Comment: It is difficult to help without an example I can replicate. Unfortunately I can't reproduce df_churn. 
Perhaps if you tell me the R output from running  class(df_churn)  and  str(df_churn[10:15])  that might give me some more information